# PHP Running 1/2 An IF Statement Without Correct Validation

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

Just a quick note, I understand my PHP code is messy and I know I could fix a lot of it with an array.

So this page is used to display vehicle details that are stored in multiple tables, the record will either equal 1 or 2. 1 being Yes it has this feature and 2 being no it doesn't. Then in my styling later on I check IF it equals 1 and if it does, then display some text so the user can see what features the vehicle has. My styling prints a little blue tick next to the text just to look nice. It only prints this tick if the vehicle has a feature, but for some reason it's printing the tick randomly. It doesn't match either, so in my code if there is 5 things the vehicle doesn't have then it might only print 1 blank tick or 2, it's not consistent and I can't figure out why!

[Image of the affected area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhXJn.png)

**Initial PHP Code**

```
//Fetch Category - Most Popular
$queryThree = "SELECT * FROM categoryMostPopular WHERE vehicleReg = :reg";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($queryThree);
$stmt->bindValue(':reg', $vehicleReg);
$stmt->execute();
$category1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Put Results Into Variables
$mostPopularReg = $category1['vehicleReg'];
$airCon = $category1['airCon'];
$bluetooth = $category1['bluetooth'];
$climateControl = $category1['climateControl'];
$satNav = $category1['satNav'];
$commsPack = $category1['commsPack'];
$climateZonex2 = $category1['climateZonex2'];
$dvdPlayer = $category1['dvdPlayer'];
$fullLeather = $category1['fullleather'];
$halfLeather = $category1['halfLeather'];
$ipodConnectivity = $category1['ipodConnectivity'];
$manufacturersDirect = $category1['manufacturersDirect'];
$memorySeats = $category1['memorySeats'];
$panarRoof = $category1['panarRoof'];
$elecFoldingMirrors = $category1['elecFoldingMirrors'];
$rainSenseWipers = $category1['rainSenseWipers'];
$xenonHeadlights = $category1['xenonHeadlights'];
```

I haven't posted all the Initial PHP code mainly because i've got 12 categories the same as the above, so it would be a lot of code.

**Check IF variable is set to 1 or 2, then display tick and text**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul class="fa-ul list-unstyled">
        <?php
        if ($alcantaraLeather == 1) { echo "<li><i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i>Alcantara Leather</li>"; }
        if ($clothUpholstery == 1) { echo "<li><i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i>Cloth Upholstery</li>"; }
        if ($velourTrim == 1) { echo "<li><i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i>Velour Trim</li>"; }
        if ($fullLeather == 1) { echo "<li><i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i>Full Leather</li>"; }
        if ($halfLeather == 1) { echo "<li><i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i>Half Leather</li>"; }
        if ($elecFoldingMirrors == 1) { echo "<li><i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i>Electric Folding Mirrors</li>"; }
        if ($rainSenseWipers == 1) { echo "<li><i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i>Rain Sense Wipers</li>"; }
        if ($xenonHeadlights == 1) { echo "<li><i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i>Xenon Headlights</li>"; }
        if ($electricSeats == 1) { echo "<li><i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i><li><i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i>Electric Seats</li>"; }
        if ($frontCentreArmrest == 1) { echo "<li><i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i><li><i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i>Front Centre Armrest</li>"; }
        if ($headRestraints == 1) { echo "<li><i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i><li><i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i>Head Restraints</li>"; }
        if ($heatedSeats == 1) { echo "<li><i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i><li><i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i>Heated Seats</li>"; }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div> <!-- end .col-sm-6 -->
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone can have a look and see why the random ticks are appearing.

[After making adjustments to the code, as mentioned by another user. This is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SFHZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are a few things that could be improved here.

1. In programming When you are dealing with an "all or nothing" condition (boolean values), then you should use 0 for NO (or FALSE) and 1 for YES (or TRUE).
2. You have two `<li>` in some of the lines like the "Electric Seats" one.
3. The `if` statements that you have are going to hide the entire text if the vehicle does not have that feature. You need to wrap the if statement only around the check mark.
4. Finally, to make the code for readable, I am suggesting using the echo shorthand `<?= $variable; ?>`

After applying those suggestions to your code, you get this ...

```php
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul class="fa-ul list-unstyled">
        <?php
        $checkMark = "<i class='fa-li fa fa-check'></i> "; // Leave the extra trailing space in this string.
        ?>
        <?php if($alcantaraLeather == 1): ?><li><?= $checkMark; ?>Alcantara Leather</li><?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($clothUpholstery == 1): ?><li><?= $checkMark; ?>Cloth Upholstery</li><?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($velourTrim == 1): ?><li><?= $checkMark; ?>Velour Trim</li><?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($fullLeather == 1): ?><li><?= $checkMark; ?>Full Leather</li><?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($halfLeather == 1): ?><li><?= $checkMark; ?>Half Leather</li><?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($elecFoldingMirrors == 1): ?><li><?= $checkMark; ?>Electric Folding Mirrors</li><?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($rainSenseWipers == 1): ?><li><?= $checkMark; ?>Rain Sense Wipers</li><?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($xenonHeadlights == 1): ?><li><?= $checkMark; ?>Xenon Headlights</li><?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($electricSeats == 1): ?><li><?= $checkMark; ?>Electric Seats</li><?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($frontCentreArmrest == 1): ?><li><?= $checkMark; ?>Front Centre Armrest</li><?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($headRestraints == 1): ?><li><?= $checkMark; ?>Head Restraints</li><?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($heatedSeats == 1): ?><li><?= $checkMark; ?>Heated Seats</li><?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
</div> <!-- end .col-sm-6 -->
```

Comment: Hm that still displays the text but not the checkmark. On features that retrun 'false' I don't want the checkmark or text to appear. So only features that return true get displayed. I'm not to sure how you use shorthand IF statements...

Comment: Oh I see. Then why add the check marks at all? Checkmark imply that they could be there or not. I will adjust the answer to hide the features and the checkbox then.

Comment: It just looked nicer by adding the checkmarks instead of having a boring list. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Its probably your style sheet (CSS File) defaulting the 'li' tag to a tick. On chrome the default is bullet point.

So create a CSS file and change the styling for the 'li' tag.

Hope this helps.

```html
element.style {
}
user agent stylesheet
li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
```